# C# JSON.net not properly creating objects as values in dictionary on deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a "Settings" class containing a dictionary with values of a "InputBindings" class. Using JSON.NET, it correctly writes/serializes the settings data into a .json file, but upon reading/deserializing the file it doesn't create the objects correctly.

I tried using "TypeNameHandling" and "Custom JsonConverter T", but I'm not sure if I used them correctly, and it didn't solve my problem as tried. I've been looking at the documentation, and I'm just not sure what to try at this point. I'm not sure why it is serializing everything correctly but not deserializing it correctly.

Here are the relevant classes, stripped of some unnecessary stuff like the enums, logging stuff, and the default values I'm assigning the dictionaries.

```
public static class PlayerInput
{
    public static Settings InputSettings { get; private set; } = new Settings();

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        SetSettingsToDefaults();
        FileOps.WriteSettingsToFile();
        FileOps.ReadSettingsFromFile();
    }
}

public class Settings
{
    public PlayerInput.MovementStyleEnum MovementStyle { get; set; } = PlayerInput.MovementStyleEnum.ScreenSpace;
    public PlayerInput.InputModeEnum InputMode { get; set; } = PlayerInput.InputModeEnum.KeyboardAndMouse;
    public Dictionary<InputBinding.GameInputsEnum, InputBinding> InputBindingsKBM { get; set; } = new Dictionary<InputBinding.GameInputsEnum, InputBinding>();
    public Dictionary<InputBinding.GameInputsEnum, InputBinding> InputBindingsController { get; set; } = new Dictionary<InputBinding.GameInputsEnum, InputBinding>();
}

public class InputBinding
{
    public GameInputsEnum InputName { get; private set; }
    public InputTypeEnum InputType { get; private set; }
    public string InputButton { get; private set; }
    public KeyCode InputKey { get; private set; }
    public int InputMouseButton { get; private set; }

    public InputBinding(GameInputsEnum _inputName, InputTypeEnum _inputType, string _inputButton, KeyCode _inputKey, int _mouseButton)
    {
        this.InputName = _inputName;
        this.InputType = _inputType;
        this.InputButton = _inputButton;
        this.InputKey = _inputKey;
        this.InputMouseButton = _mouseButton;
    }
}

public static class FileOps
{
    private const string SettingsFilePath = "Settings.json";

    public static bool ReadSettingsFromFile()
    {
        if(File.Exists(SettingsFilePath) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Settings settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(File.ReadAllText(SettingsFilePath));
            // Looping through the dictionaries in settings here is where the objects don't seem to properly reflect what is written in the .json file
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void WriteSettingsToFile()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(SettingsFilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PlayerInput.InputSettings, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

FileOps.WriteSettingsToFile() correctly creates a .json file that looks as it should. See https://pastebin.com/DZ5paXgY

When i use some foreach loops to loop through the settings read by FileOps.ReadSettingsFromFile(), it shows that it isn't creating the InputBinding objects in the dictionaries correctly. See https://pastebin.com/FP2DaAaE

The dictionaries' keys are populated correctly, but the values are the same default values repeated for each key.

For example:

"Pause : Submit, , None, 0"

from line 6 of the output should look like

"Pause : Pause, , 27, 0" which reflects what you see starting on line 19 of the .json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use underscores in parameter names. Underscore-prefix should only be used for fields not parameters. Secondly JSON.NET can't map the JSON properties to your constructor parameters because of the underscores.

Remove the underscores and JSON.NET will be able to map the JSON to the parameters.

```
public class InputBinding
{
    public GameInputsEnum InputName { get; private set; }
    public InputTypeEnum InputType { get; private set; }
    public string InputButton { get; private set; }
    public KeyCode InputKey { get; private set; }
    public int InputMouseButton { get; private set; }

    public InputBinding(GameInputsEnum inputName, InputTypeEnum inputType, string inputButton, KeyCode inputKey, int mouseButton)
    {
        this.InputName = inputName;
        this.InputType = inputType;
        this.InputButton = inputButton;
        this.InputKey = inputKey;
        this.InputMouseButton = mouseButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. That was a much simpler solution than I was expecting. Thanks for the information.